# Check if geo-location has been spoofed

Tags: android, gps, location, position

I want to make sure the location received by the LocationListener is a "real" one and doesn't come from a spoofed source (I.e the Application [Location Spoofer](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.ajeje.fakelocation)). I don't care about "but the user sometimes want to spoof the location" - it's about an app which doesnt get distributed over the android market. The application does not need the location to be that accurate - it just has to be "real".

Do you think there is a way to check if the location has been spoofed?
What do you think is a good way to prevent location spoofing?
Is there maybe a android-method which gives me the real location nevertheless?
Is there maybe a android-method to determine if the location has been spoofed?

Thoughts I had:

- Check on a blacklist if a location-spoofing app is installed
- Enable/disable different location providers and check against their returned locations
- Run a background service watching the location (in a passive way) and check for sudden location changes

Please give me your thoughts and input to this issue.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

- From the Provider name: 'gps' or 'network' are proper
- Most spoofers forget to send GPS status updates. That is something that you can use to your advantage

  `// returns true if mock location enabled, false if not enabled.`

  ```
  if (Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),
         Settings.Secure.ALLOW_MOCK_LOCATION).equals("0")) 
         return false; 
         else return true;
  ```

The best method is this :

- Mock location providers do not send NMEA data. So create a NMEA listener. If you don't get NMEA update but you get valid GPS updates in onLocationChanged() a spoof is being used.

Comment: Hi Reno, I don't know NMEA listener? How can you guide clearly?

Comment: ALLOW_MOCK_LOCATION is deprecated

Comment: Apps like Fake GPS Go send the NMEA, any idea on how to catch this type of fake Locations?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look on "Maintaining a current best estimate" topic on the following page:

[Maintaining a current best estimate](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html)